# Обработка XML прайсов

Tags: xml, php, mysql

Всем привет!

Хочу реализовать обработку прайсов формата XML.

Вопрос в том, как это все обыграть удобно?

Если в прайсе несколько тысяч или несколько десятков тысяч товаров, то как с этим массивом работать?

Нужно будет выводить список товаров с постраничкой, чтобы можно было перед загрузкой внести нужные изменения. Например, изменить категорию на нужную или название, цену... Потом сохранить изменения и уже заливать в БД.

Как тут быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсить xml sax парсером (при больших списках это будет быстрее) и хранить в базе (поэлементно). Это сильно упросит вывод и модификацию. А сохранить потом с базы в файл - это уже не проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала парсить и заливать как есть в базу данных, после редактирования сохранять окончательно (проставлять флаг, перекладывать в настоящую таблицу, это как хотите). Парсить, как уже сказали, с помощью sax.

Comment: А если прйсов 50 штук. Как в БД лить? На каждый свою временную таблицу создавать?

Про SAX спасибо. Вопрос. А нет ли готовой класса-обертки под SAX? Погуглил, что-то ничего не нашел толком.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Просто добавьте в таблицу еще одно поле - идентификатор прайса. Ну и поэлементное хранение уже предлагалось выше - оно тоже не лишено смысла. А по поводу обертки не совсем понимаю - зачем?